# Customizing a continuous legend in Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, legend, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, color-ramp

I've created legends in ggplot, which look like this

[image: r ggplot legend]

With the code I've used in Google Earth Engine, this is what my legend looks like

[image: gee legend]

Is there an easy way for me to edit my Google Earth Engine code to have it match what I've been making in ggplot? Code is as shown below.

```
 // Choose the yellow, orange, red colour palette with 9 classes
var palette = palettes.colorbrewer.YlOrRd[9];
var vis = {min: 0, max: 335, palette: palette};

// Create a mask to remove 0 values
merchantable = merchantable.updateMask(merchantable.neq(0));

// Add a raster layer and enable the colour palette
Map.addLayer(merchantable, {min: 0, max: 335, palette: palette});

// Creates a color bar thumbnail image for use in legend from the given color palette
function makeColorBarParams(palette) {
  return {
    bbox: [0, 0, 1, 0.1],
    dimensions: '100x10',
    format: 'png',
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    palette: palette,
  };
}

// Create the colour bar for the legend
var colorBar = ui.Thumbnail({
  image: ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select(0),
  params: makeColorBarParams(vis.palette),
  style: {stretch: 'horizontal', margin: '0px 8px', maxHeight: '24px'},
});

// Create a panel with three numbers for the legend
var legendLabels = ui.Panel({
  widgets: [
    ui.Label(vis.min, {margin: '4px 8px'}),
    ui.Label(
        ((vis.max-vis.min) / 2+vis.min),
        {margin: '4px 8px', textAlign: 'center', stretch: 'horizontal'}),
    ui.Label(vis.max, {margin: '4px 8px'})
  ],
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal')
});

// Legend title
var legendTitle = ui.Label({
  value: 'Merchantable (tons C)',
  style: {fontWeight: 'bold'}
});

// Add the legendPanel to the map
var legendPanel = ui.Panel([legendTitle, colorBar, legendLabels]);
Map.add(legendPanel);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the color bar, you're using a `pixelLatLon` image, in the region of 0 to 1, with a min/max of 0/1, so you get a continuous spread of color (using 100 values from 0 to 1).  To get discrete steps, use a larger range and truncate the numbers to integers.  The following code produces 10 steps by using the region 0 to 10, with a max of 10.

```
var nSteps = 10
// Creates a color bar thumbnail image for use in legend from the given color palette
function makeColorBarParams(palette) {
  return {
    bbox: [0, 0, nSteps, 0.1],
    dimensions: '100x10',
    format: 'png',
    min: 0,
    max: nSteps,
    palette: palette,
  };
}

// Create the colour bar for the legend
var colorBar = ui.Thumbnail({
  image: ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select(0).int(),
  params: makeColorBarParams(vis.palette),
  style: {stretch: 'horizontal', margin: '0px 8px', maxHeight: '24px'},
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8c935da8a1f2a22f0c4b382e2267117b